# Can not change array data with map function

Tags: javascript

I have `data` and `selectedProfessional`, they are array with json object, use the same structure.

Json obejct structure:

```
{"id":1,"store_id":1,"united":0,"name":"Max","title":"設計師","max_booking_number":null,"price":2000,"seniority":5,"image":"https://polipoli.s3.amazonaws.com/share/professional/professional1.jpg","desc":"Explicabo in excepturi aspernatur.","skill":"Asperiores in dicta pariatur. Illum ut ut nulla.","store_name":"FEETUP 美甲工作室","selected":true}
```

I want to compare `selectedProfessional` id with `data` id and change data's argument with `selected` true or false.

Here is my code:

```
const { data } = response;
  console.log('first data', data);
  console.log('selectedProfessional', selectedProfessional);
  data.map(option => {
    selectedProfessional.map(value => {
      if (value.id === option.id) {
        console.log('1');
        option.selected = true;
      } else {
        option.selected = false;
      }
    });
  });
  console.log('final data', data);
```

Here is the result print:
[image]

I think my final data id 1 and 2 object's selected should be true, but it is only id 2 is true.

I have no idea why.

Comment: Does the `Data` have the `selected` property set to `false` by default?

Comment: remove the `else { ... }` block and u r fine;

Comment: Thanks for everyone, remove the else { ... } is working, I know what is my issue now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can return a new array with an updated selected flag where id is found inside `selectedProfessional` array:

```
updatedData = data.map(option => selectedProfessional.map(v => v.id).indexOf(option.id) > -1 ? {
   ...option,
   selected: true
} : option);

console.log( updatedData );
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works !  I found my issue now.

Answer (score 1):

Here is readable and efficient way to achieve that;

```js
const  data =[
{"id":1,"store_id":1,"otherAttr":"...","selected":true},
{"id":2,"store_id":2,"otherAttr":"...","selected":true},
{"id":3,"store_id":3,"otherAttr":"...","selected":true},
{"id":4,"store_id":4,"otherAttr":"...","selected":true}
];

const selectedProfessional = [
{"id":2,"otherAttr":"..."}, 
{"id":4,"otherAttr":"..."}
];
  
 let newData = data.map(option => {
    // making sure options are not selected initially
    option.selected = false;
    let isFoundInSelectedProfessional = selectedProfessional.some(sp=> sp.id == option.id);
    if(isFoundInSelectedProfessional){
        console.log(`id ${option.id} selected to be true`);
        option.selected = true;
    }
    return option
  });
  
  console.log('final data', newData);
```